# Populate a DropDown/Select based on the value chosen on another DropDown using JSON in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have 2 dropdowns, on selecting value in one dropdown should make an ajax call using JSON and populate the value in another dropdown. This needs to be done in EXT JS. Could anyone post the code or provide the approach?
Thanks
-Praveen

Comment: Praveen, what version of ExtJS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ext.data.HttpProxy` combined with `Ext.data.JsonReader` to do that. Well written example : http://www.sk-typo3.de/ExtJS-Dynamische-Comboboxen.337.0.html